Python - aiohttp , Catch outages session , timeout = None
I have task to download video .
Timeout = None because Videos may take more than 24 hours to load .
But if the server from which I download goes offline, the code freezes because timeout = None .
How to catch ??
async with session.get(url,timeout=None) as response_get:
    with open('filename.ext', 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = await response_get.read(16144)  
            if not chunk: 
            break
           f.write(chunk)

Thanks in advance !
I tried to create another task, but I still couldn’t figure out how to complete another task from that task.
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aio_ping import ping

download_cancel = asyncio.Event()

async def is_network_available():
    result = ping ( host)
    return result

async def download_file(url, filename, network_available):
    while True:
        await network_available.wait()  

        if download_cancel.is_set():
            print
            return

async def main():
    network_available = asyncio.Event()
    network_task = asyncio.create_task(is_network_available(network_available))
    download_task = asyncio.create_task(download_file('https://example.com/large_file.zip', 'large_file.zip', network_available))

    await asyncio.gather(network_task, download_task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

